# HTTP status code 405 error for post method

Tags: angularjs

I am able to consume get api and working fine but for post method getting error as

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://183.82.48.194:84/HospitalManagementSystem/Service1.svc/LoginVerification. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
```

I have disabled websecurity in browser also but getting same error,
If i run in rest client i am able to get the response,can anyone tell me what is the problem

Comment: make sure your files have necessary permissions on the server

Comment: better use GET instead of POST as reference to : http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html

Comment: @DipeshParmar for api's they are using wcf framework, do they need to change anything

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post data with url like this

http://183.82.48.194:84/HospitalManagementSystem/Service1.svc/LoginVerification

for this you should use

(http://183.82.48.194:84/HospitalManagementSystem/Service1.svc,LoginVerification)

Comment: i have not got ur answer

Comment: http://183.82.48.194:84/HospitalManagementSystem/Service1.svc/LoginVerification   is the api give how can i change that

Comment: is the LoginVerification is the part of url  or service name?

Comment: what is the object you want to post?

Comment: emailId and password

Comment: For more than one parameter we use get request

Comment: in order to use it as a post you should move it to a single class object and then use post request

Comment: i think we can use post method also, may be issue here is cors

Comment: I use this method $http.post(http://183.82.48.194:84/HospitalManagementSystem/Service1.svc/LoginVerification,data you want to transfer);

Comment: try moving these two thing to one object and than pass this object as parameter and make changes accordingly in api